# AngularJS ng-repeat - jquery Datepicker not working inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-ng-repeat

jQuery datepicker not working inside a AngularJS ng-repeat block.

Not sure if anything wrong in code generation inside ng-repeat block. The same logic works outside ng-repeat.

**Working code**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">TEST DATE</label>
            <div class="input-group col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="testDate" name="testDate" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Not working code**

```
        <div ng-repeat="reportType in reportTypes">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">{{reportType.reportTypeLabel}}</label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" id="{{reportType.reportTypeCodeId}}Date" readonly="readonly"
                        class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Date picker dd/mm/yyyy
$(function() {
    $("input[id*='date']").datepicker({
        dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("input[id*='Date']").datepicker({
        dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
```

Comment: This is just wrong way to mix angular and jquery. ng-repeat may add or remove elements, when your jquery code runs only once. Wrap all jquery to directives or just do not use it at all - use angular datepicker instead.

Comment: Create a date-picker directive. Use jQueryLite with datepicker for the `element`, make sure you cleanup on $scope destroy to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this directive to initialize the datepicker after ng-repeat ends:

```
angular.module('mymodule').directive('ngOnFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit(attr.broadcastEventName ? attr.broadcastEventName : 'ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(){        
    $("input[id*='date']").datepicker({
        dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy"
    });        
});
```

In your view, add the directive `ng-on-finish-render` to element with `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="reportType in reportTypes" ng-on-finish-render>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">{{reportType.reportTypeLabel}}</label>
            <div class="input-group col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="{{reportType.reportTypeCodeId}}Date" readonly="readonly"
                    class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can add `broadcast-event-name="myNgRepeatFinished"` parameter if you have more than one ng-repeat in your scope and they have different purposes

```
$scope.$on('myNgRepeatFinished', function(){        
    $("input[id*='date']").datepicker({
        dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy"
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom directive for the datepicker.

The View

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<div ng-repeat="report in repArray">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{report.values.name}}</label>
        <input type="text" datepicker ng-model="datevalue" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The Directive

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.report = [
        { 'name': 'rep1' },
        { 'name': 'rep2' },
        { 'name': 'rep3' }
    ]

    $scope.repArray = Object.keys($scope.report)
        .map(function (value, index) {
            return { values: $scope.report[value] }
        }
    );
} ]);


myApp.directive("datepicker", function () {

    function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
    }

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link
    };
});
```